# Redis command to list all subscribers subscribed to redis channel

Tags: javascript, redis, node-redis

Below command only gives channel list .

```
127.0.0.1:6379> PUBSUB CHANNELS
1) "mychannel"
2) "mychanne2"
```

**How to LIST subscribers subscribed on channel1 OR channel2 .?**

also

i din't found redis command to list all subscribers Of a particular channel

Answer (score 9):

You can use `PUBSUB NUMSUB channel1` OR `PUBSUB NUMSUB channel2` and get reply about the number of subscribers for the specified channel.

Answer (score 2):

I can achieve this with something like:

```
redis_client.multi().client(['list']).exec(function(err, results) {
  var pairs = results[0].split(' ');
  pairs.forEach(function(pair){
    var kv = pair.split('=');
    if (kv[0] == 'name' && kv[1] == constants.REDIS_SUBSCRIBER_NAME)
      found = true;
  });
  if (found) // some logic
  else // some logic
});
```

Comment: what  should i put in if condition in place of `name` && `constants.REDIS_SUBSCRIBER_NAME`

Comment: i required('redis') , then created redis_client client , then fired this script in node and it says `constants is not defined`

Comment: This is a name you can set to your subscriber client. `subscriber.client('setname', constants.REDIS_SUBSCRIBER_NAME);`. **Use your own name**.

Comment: i have created a sample of what i did .. but from this sample i am not able to come to any conclusion.github sample [github sample list_subscribers_of_redis_channels](https://github.com/pawarvijay/list_subscribers_of_redis_channels)

Comment: also in github sample [github sample list_subscribers_of_redis_channels](https://github.com/pawarvijay/list_subscribers_of_redis_channels) i have console.log in many places and not able to make out subscribers subscribed on channel1 Or channnel2

Comment: am i missing any thing in sample

Comment: Don't change `kv[0] == 'name'`. This is a value from Redis.

Comment: You can also use `redis_client.client('setname', 'YOVIJAY')` instead of `CLIENT SETNAME 'YOVIJAY'`